# Is there a simple way to remove the marked property from the div, with typescript or Javascript?

Tags: html, css

I m trying to build a button that contains three spans and I want to split the button into three tiles. One with a image and the other two with text.

The button is from fluent UI from Microsoft.

[image: image of the properties]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the _"marked property"_? Thanks. Oh... do you mean you want to edit the `display` property ?

Comment: Yes the display property. But the problem is that ":host .control" is generated by fluent ui through the fluent button https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/components/button.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way to update the CSS `display` property using JavaScript is:

```
myButton.style.setProperty('display', newValue);
```